# SQL searching daily attributes error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build an application which searches all attributes step by step daily and monthly using the between statement. The daily queries run, but monthly dones't run.

The code:

```
 if (libs.conn.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) libs.conn.baglanti.Open();
     string today = "select getdate()";
  SqlCommand today1 = new SqlCommand(today, libs.conn.con);
    string today2 = today1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    string[] day = today2.Split(' ');
     day[0] += " 00:00:00";
      string dayy = (DateTime.Now.Day).ToString();
       string month = (DateTime.Now.Month).ToString();
  string year = (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString();
    string[] combine = new string[] { "1." };
        combine[0] += month + ".";
           combine[0] += year + " ";
       combine[0] += "00:00:00";
       string totalmonth = "(SELECT SUM(para) FROM statistics where datee between            '"+combine[0]+"' AND '"+today2+"')";
     SqlCommand totalmoneymonthlyquery = new SqlCommand(totalmoneymonth,                 libs.conn.baglanti);
     string totalmoneymonthlyresult = totalmoneymonthlyquery.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            textBox7.Text = totalmoneymonthlyresult.ToString();
```

Comment: what error do you get for the monthly query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 combine[0]=today2
```

use first

you may get parameter error to pull data.

```
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); 
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt);
```